# logstash file input in read mode for gzip file is consuming very high memory

Tags: node.js, logstash, logstash-file

Currently i am processing gzip files in logstash using file input plugin. its consuming very high memory and keeps on restarting even after giving a high heap size. As of now on an avg we are processing 50 files per min and the planning to process 1000's of file per min. With 100 files the RAM requirement touches 10Gb. What is the best way to tune this config or is there a better way to process such a huge volume of data in logstash. 
 is it advisable to write a processing engine in nodejs or any other languages.

Below is the logstash conf.

```
input {
  file {
    id => "client-files"
    mode => "read"
    path => [ "/usr/share/logstash/plugins/message/*.gz" ]
    codec => "json"
    file_completed_action => log_and_delete
    file_completed_log_path => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/processed.log"
  }
}
filter {
  ruby {
    code => 'monitor_name = event.get("path").split("/").last.split("_").first
             event.set("monitorName", monitor_name )
             split_field = []
             event.get(monitor_name).each do |x|
               split_field << Hash[event.get("Datapoints").zip(x)]
             end
             event.set("split_field",split_field)'
  }
  split {
    field => "split_field"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event.get('split_field').each {|k,v| event.set(k,v)}"
    remove_field => ["split_field","Datapoints","%{monitorName}"]
  }
}
```